# How to use colors in RGB as the input domain in a d3.js linear (or different) scale? Or how to code an algorithm that achieves the same?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Is it possible to do something like the following?

```
var color = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain(["rgb(0,255,0)","rgb(255,0,0)"])
    .range([1,10]);
```

I would like to achive something such as:

```
var output = color( d3.rgb("rgb(255,0,0)") );
console.log(output); // Prints 10.
```

If not, any other kind of code would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Essentially, you are asking a [duplicate of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29280111/invert-a-color-scale-in-d3-js).  I won't vote to close, though, in case things have changed and it's now possible (I can't see an easy way to make it work though).

Comment: how come you want to have a colour scale when you are effectively setting the colour via rgb(255,0,0) ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my stab at this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="d3@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script>
      var range = [0,10],
        inter = d3.interpolate("rgb(0,255,0)","rgb(255,0,0)");

      var s = d3.scaleBand() 
        .domain(d3.range(0,1,0.001).map(d => inter(d)))
        .range(range);

      console.log(s("rgb(0, 255, 0)"));
      console.log(s("rgb(255, 0, 0)"));
      console.log(s("rgb(128, 128, 0)"));
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```